# how to use srv in another package?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi.
i want to use the srv file that i have created in some package and use it ( include it ) in another package ,
what should i do ?
thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202312/how-to-use-srv-in-another-package?/) by [babaksn](https://answers.ros.org/users/21552/babaksn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This other package has to depend on the package that contains the srv file. (build and run depend in your CMakeLists.txt)

Then you include the service in the source file where you need it.

Everything is well explained in the tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1